# Скрипт на Python для автоматического ввода

Tags: python

Привет всем.
Понадобилось написать скрипт один на python, и он почти сразу вызвал затруднения. Опыт работы с питоном небольшой, так что надеюсь на подсказку.
Итак, задача. Есть некая консольная программа, в которую требуется вводить команды и она будет выдавать ответ, на основе этого ответа нужно вводить какие нибудь еще команды и тд. От скрипта требуется, чтобы он запускал ее и основываясь на выводе вводил каккие нб данные и тд.
Я пытался организовать их диалог через subprocess.communicate, но насколько я понял с его помощью можно только один раз подать строку на вход. Всякие там pipe.stdin.writeline() и pipe.stdout.readlines() не дают ожидаемого эффекта. Как лучше организовать взаимодействие скрипта и этой программы, может подскажите рецепт?

Comment: @vlol "Огласите весь список, пжалста!". Код опубликуйте (в разумных пределах)

Comment: Похоже, что вы пытаетесь изобрести [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

```
import subprocess

print subprocess.check_output("ping -n 3 ya.ru")
```